# Changing Masonry's columnWidth option on resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-masonry

I'm using this plugin: http://masonry.desandro.com/

I currently initialise the plugin for 960px layouts and my code for this is:

```
<script>

$(function(){

    var $container = $('#container');

    $container.imagesLoaded( function(){
      $container.masonry({
        itemSelector : '.box',
        gutterWidth: 8,
            // Want to change this here:
        columnWidth: 113
      });
    });

  });
</script>
```

I want to change the columnWidth number from 113 to 146 when the screen width or browser window width is higher than 1225px. How do I do this?

Comment: Screen width or browser width? You're going to need to pick -- one is constant; one is under user control after your page has loaded

Comment: Well, I need both really. Resizing the window, my layout breaks and needs a refresh to fix. I also want to display the correct layout based on their screen size, so if a user has 1024x768 resolution I push the 960px layout rather than the larger one. Can I not have both?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
columnWidth: $(document).width() > 1225 ? 146 : 113
```

Comment: This works really well but when I resize the browser, the layout breaks. To fix the layout I have to refresh. Is there a way to use this method but perhaps enhance it to stop it from breaking on resize, without having to refresh the page? I.e. I can resize browser and the layout is correct no matter what.

Comment: from http://masonry.desandro.com/docs/intro.html
Changelog
v2.1: 9 Dec 2011
Pass in a function for columnWidth for easier fluid layouts

Comment: Could you advise how I 'Pass in a function for columnWidth for easier fluid layouts', I'm not great with JS. All the help appreciated. :)

Comment: columnWidth: function () { $(document).widht() > 1225 ? 146: 113; }
I think this should work I've never used masonry but from my review this seems like it should work.

Comment: I took your code but added $(window).bind('resize',function(){
      window.location.href = window.location.href;
 }); and it worked just fine in the end. Thanks!

Comment: @egr103 Where exactly did you add that last bit? I'm in the exact same position you were in. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing this on window resize, then you want to attach a handler to the resize event. In your event handler, call $(yourdiv).masonry({columnWidth: }) if appropriate.

You will probably also want to look into th jquery.resize plugin here: http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-resize-plugin/ -- some (most) browsers will send resize events *constantly* while the window is being resized, and that could result in a lot of re-layout if the user hovers right around the threshold.

Comment: Not quite sure how I'd use that plugin to get what I want. Could you advise at all?